# How to detect ring tone in freeswitch dialplan?

Tags: freeswitch, dialplan

After dialing to a remote callcenter and getting past the IVR, my customer's staff usually end up waiting a long time for an agent to pickup, while listening to hold music. I am considering a possibility where they can transfer the call to a dialplan on their local freeswitch, which awaits the ringtone of the remote agent. Once the dialplan detects that the agent phone ringing, it should forward the call back to the original caller.

There are not many examples for tone_detect application. Assuming it is US ring tone, how should the tone specification look like?

```
<action application="tone_detect" data="ring 440,480 r 0 transfer '1000 XML default' 2">
```

I doubt the above will work because, US ring tone plays 440+480 Hz on for 2000ms off for 4000ms. I am not sure how I can specify that.

Answer (score 0):

That's a great idea.  A call metaqueue.  The tone detect, if it worked wouldn't be foolproof as sometimes the bridge won't get ring back.  You might consider monitoring energy level as well to wait for a period of silence short energy then again silence (a hello sequence). Your arguments for the command - [Detect Tone](https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Misc._Dialplan_Tools_tone_detect) look correct for the old syntax, but you might update to the newer preferred behavior also herein.

Comment: You mean I should use the media bug to get the audio and then measure the levels? Looks like I'll have to write a module then. Any existing FS app/api that does it already?

Comment: I was thinking a lot easier, you could use flow control within the dial plan something like this <action application="wait_for_silence" data="200 50 10 30000"/>

Comment: Hmm, let's me try that and get back.